# have no idea what the exception is here

Tags: csv, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file. using below command:

```
sample = pd.read_csv("C:/kushal/DataMining/hillary/out.txt" ,header = 0, delimiter = "\t")
```

Unfortunately it gives me some exception about which I have no idea what is causing it. Does anyone knows anything about this exception

```
    sample["ExtractedBodyText"][1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#75>", line 1, in <module>
    hillary["ExtractedBodyText"][1]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1914, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1921, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1090, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3102, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1692, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3979)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3843)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 668, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12265)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 676, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12216)
KeyError: 'ExtractedBodyText'
```

Comment: Your data frame does not seem to have a column named `ExtractedBodyText`.

Comment: This is what I get when I run before comment. I think it is there:


 >>> sample.columns.values
 array([ 'Id,DocNumber,MetadataSubject,MetadataTo,MetadataFrom,SenderPersonId,MetadataDateSent,MetadataDateReleased,MetadataPdfLink,MetadataCaseNumber,MetadataDocumentClass,ExtractedSubject,ExtractedTo,ExtractedFrom,ExtractedCc,ExtractedDateSent,ExtractedCaseNumber,ExtractedDocNumber,ExtractedDateReleased,ExtractedReleaseInPartOrFull,ExtractedBodyText,RawText'], dtype=object)

Comment: The header is separated by comma, but you set the separator to tabs.